# MapKit - transit type for MKDirectionsRequest() not Working

Tags: swift, swift3, mapkit, mkdirection

Now I'm doing somethig nice with Swift 3, I hope: Calculating a route between 2 places.
I am using the Xcode simulator.
I can calculate it by car, walking, or with transit.

This is what I have:

```
mapview.delegate = self
let request = MKDirectionsRequest()
request.source = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.203314, longitude: -8.410257), addressDictionary: nil))
    request.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.112808, longitude: -8.498689), addressDictionary: nil))
    request.requestsAlternateRoutes = false
    //request.transportType = .automobile
    request.transportType = .transit

    let directions = MKDirections(request: request)

    directions.calculate { [unowned self] response, error in
        guard let unwrappedResponse = response else { return }

        for route in unwrappedResponse.routes {
            self.mapview.add(route.polyline)
            self.mapview.setVisibleMapRect(route.polyline.boundingMapRect, animated: true)
            print("Distance: \(route.distance/1000) m")
            print("ETA: \(route.expectedTravelTime/60) min")


            for step in route.steps {
                print(step.instructions)
            }


        }

    }
```

I've set the code, and everything works for car or walking. However, transit options is not doing anything.

Why is that?

Comment: Transit information might not be available at your location

Comment: Oh I see. but If transit information was available it should work, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directions are not available for transportType .transit unfortunately, only ETA

[Related Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38603138/transit-mkdirectionsrequest-produces-null-error-error-domain-mkerrordomain-code)